# Where is error in regexp (java)?

Tags: java, regex

I have xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            </head>
            <body>


<div>&nbsp;</div>

            Hello body content !!

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="br-replace">
        <xsl:param name="word"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($word,'&#xA;')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($word,'&#xA;')"/>
                <br xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="br-replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="word" select="substring-after($word,'&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$word"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="format-date">
        <xsl:param name="word"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($word, 1, 10)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</stylesheet>
```

I am trying split it into three parts:

1. text before `<body>`
2. text between `<body> and </body>`
3. text after `</body>`

Java code:

```
Matcher before = Pattern.compile("(.*?)<body>", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                .matcher(input);
        String beforeStr = null;
        if (before.find()) {
            beforeStr = before.group(1);
        }

        Matcher after = Pattern.compile("</body>(.*?)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                .matcher(input);
        String afterStr = null;
        if (after.find()) {
            afterStr = after.group(1);
        }

        Matcher body = Pattern.compile("<body>(.*?)</body>",
                Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(input);
            String bodyStr = null;
        if (body.find()) {
            bodyStr= body.group(1);
        }
```

Any idea why String 'afterStr' is empty, something is wrong with pattern?

Comment: Why don't you use a xml parser instead of parsing the xml with regular expressions?

Comment: No need for `Pattern.MULTILINE`, by the way - your regexes don't contain any `^` or `$` anchors.

Comment: Also you don't need to add a `?` after `*`. `*` contains zero occurrence as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-greedy quantifier, without something to its right.

```
"</body>(.*?)"
           ^matches as little as possible. In this case, 0 characters.
```

Just use a greedy match:

```
</body>(.*)
```

The above will do what you want.

Comment: I disagree with the solution. The simpler approach would be to use a greedy quantifier: `.*` - that will automatically match the rest of the string. `[\d\D]` is only needed in JavaScript where there is no `DOTALL` option.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I was confused about just that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do this textually rather than with an XML parser, wouldn't it be easier just to use `indexOf` and `substring`? Regex is the wrong tool, but if you're going to use the wrong tool, there's a better wrong tool to pick. :-)

Compare your code with this (assumes `input` is the string):

```
int indexOfBodyStart = input.indexOf("<body>");
int indexOfBodyEnd   = input.indexOf("</body>");
String beforeBody    = input.substring(0, indexOfBodyStart);
String body          = input.substring(indexOfBodyStart + 6, indexOfBodyEnd);
String afterBody     = input.substring(indexOfBodyEnd + 7);
```

This is no more or less subject to failing than the regex solution. (E.g., if the text `<body>` appears within quotes prior to the actual body, or `</body>` before the end of the body, both solutions will fail.)

Marking this CW because you specifically asked about regex.